# Python > MYSQL > json parsing doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, json, parsing

How can I parse the following json string?

> [('{"anrede":"Frau","created":{"_seconds":"1540166556","_nanoseconds":"769000000"},"datenschutz":"Datenschutzhinweise<\/a> gelesen und akzeptiert","einkommen":"ueber-800"}',)]

Backround:
The json come from a mysql select and is unchangeable (sadly).

I see two difficulties:
First: [('
Second: "datenschutz":"Datenschutzhinweise<\/a> gelesen und akzeptiert"

Comment: That's not a JSON string. `[(` <-- invalid `(`. Is that the "stringified output of a wrapping object", perhaps? If so, use the appropriate access, eg. `var jsonStr = somedata[0][0]`, *first* to actually get a/the [JSON] string.

Comment: Also, the tags are confusing - why is it tagged is Python *and* MySQL? What interaction between the two makes them both relevant? Now, *I suspect*, that the Python DB access might be returning a *list of rows-as-tuples* - ie `l = list(); t = ("json",); l.append(t); l` emits `[('json',)]`) - and the "string" claimed is really the `repr` of this result. See above.

Comment: I've tagged mysql, because it's a directly sql answer. Her is a part of the python code. 
#### code start #### 
import mysql.connector
import json
mydb=mysql.connector.connect(host=„xxxx“,port=„xx“,user=„xx“,passwd=„xx“,database=„xxxx“)
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT \
e.json_data \
FROM form_entry e \
where e.created >='2018-10-22' \
and e.form =6 \
and e.id=‚abdcdasd’“ )
myresult = mycursor.fetchall()
### code end
json_string =json.dumps(myresult)

print (myresult)

Comment: `myresult = mycursor.fetchall()`; `myresult` is *not* a string, much less a string containing JSON -- see above. I'd also like a chocolate chip cookie.

Comment: Thank's a lot. It Works !